# Can we find if 0 occurs odd number of times in an array using bit manipulation

Tags: c++, c, arrays, bit-manipulation, xor

I know that, XORing all elements of an integer array which contains all of its elements except 1 element occuring even number of times gives the number that occurs odd number of times.

**Example**

{ 1, 1, 2, 2, 3 }
1 ^ 1 ^ 2 ^ 2 ^ 3 = 3;

**^ is XOR**

What if the number occuring odd number of times is 0?
**{ 1, 1, 2, 2, 0 }**

```
1 ^ 1 ^ 2 ^ 2 ^ 0 = 0    // Both give
1 ^ 1 ^ 2 ^ 2 = 0        // same answer
```

How to confirm that 0 is occuring odd number of times
PS : Prefer the answer code to be in C/C++

Comment: Perhaps you should take some time to learn how the bitwise operators work? Not only in the language of your choice (pick one! C and C++ are two very different languages), but in general.

Comment: It seems that you have answered your own question already. You cannot tell the 0 for "only pairs" from "0 is the only single number". So what you need is a second way to find out even/odd number of zeros. Turning that around: No, not by only XORing.

Comment: That last one is not an example of "an integer array which contains all of its elements except 1 element occuring even number of times".  So it's no surprise that this trick doesn't do anything meaningful for it.

Comment: Given an input that actually has the property, it works for 0.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude hey, in bitwise operators there is no C/C++. Both have same syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's call N, the number of elements in your array:

- If (N is even) AND (XORing all elements ==0) -> All the elements occur even number of times
- if (N is odd) AND (XORing all elements ==0) -> You single element is zero.

This is how to [check if an integer is even or odd in C / C++](https://www.humblix.com/qnz3sH/how-to-check-if-an-integer-is-even-or-odd-in-c-c/)